# How to change the display name of a bulk of shared mailboxes? accentuation issue

Tags: exchange, powershell, scripting

I have to rename a bulk of shared mailboxes to a new format, the script is ready and works but when the script runs, the names that contains **accentuation** are not being updated properly and a question mark is shown where the accentuation should exist.

> -----------------------------------------input file:
>
> ```
> name,NewName
> BMS-cipatubarao,"CIPA Tubarão"
> BEL-liberacaeodelimbo-amd,"Liberação AMD"
> ```
>
> -----------------------------------------Script:
>
> ```
> $sharedChange = Import-Csv .\"SHAREDchange.csv"
> $sharedChange | foreach{
>   $sharedName = $_.name
>   $sharedNewName = $_.newname
>   try {
>   # Change the DisplayName on Services Domain
>       set-user $sharedname -displayname $sharedNewName
>       "$(get-date -f MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm:ss), $sharednewname, modified on, $sharedname`n" | out-file '.\SharedSuccess.txt' -append
>   }   catch {
>       "$(get-date -f MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm:ss), $sharednewname, NOT modified on, $sharedname`n" | out-file '.\SharedFailed.txt' -append
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> -----------------------------------------output file:
>
> ```
> 09/04/2017-17:47:12, CIPA Tubar�o, modified on, cipatubarao
> 09/04/2017-17:47:14, Libera��o AMD, modified on, liberacaeo-amd
> ```

What should I do? 
I have already tried to use the command directly on my shell using 
`set-mailbox liberacaeo-amd -displayname "Liberação AMD"` 
and it works, but as I have a batch of shared mailboxes to execute this change, this is completely out of  question.

Answer (score 2):

*At first you really should now stop using such special characters as you have seen it will be a problem when it comes to scripting ... so as you start implementing a new name schema make sure this will eliminate such ugly special characters.*

1.)
Make sure your input format has the correct encoding (e.g. UTF-8 with BOM)

2.) You can try to convert them:

```
   function ConvertTo-Encoding ([string]$From, [string]$To){
        Begin{
            $encFrom = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($from)
            $encTo = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($to)
        }
        Process{
            $bytes = $encTo.GetBytes($_)
            $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Convert($encFrom, $encTo, $bytes)
            $encTo.GetString($bytes)
        }
    }

    [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.Codepage

    $Title = "Liberação Tubarão" | ConvertTo-Encoding "UTF-8" "windows-1251"
    Write-Host $Title
    $Title = $Title.Replace(("Liberação" | ConvertTo-Encoding "UTF-8" "windows-1251"), "")
    Write-Host $Title
```

3.) You might try to set the encoding to UTF8 at first via (more infos [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/11/outputencoding-to-the-rescue/)):

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Powershell 3.0 and higher:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
```

Comment: Hi dear BastianW, the problem is that this "ugly characters" are part of the Brazilian Portuguese language, there is no way to remove it as without some words doesnt make sense. I will need to keep them, and that is why I've requested this help. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I know that from German, where they have "äöü" but there are ways to replace them, so that the meaning would be the same "ä=ae;ö=oe;ü=ue", so something like that might work in your case as well. Not every software can "handle" special (UTF-8) characters and soon or less you might run into some issues which are caused by the "special names". This is by the way the reason why Microsoft do not allow them in OUs and such objects as seen [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and).

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you are saying, but, when I do the same command using the shell directly, the name is correctly executed.

Comment: yes as mentioned above this is caused by the encoding. You might try to convert that or to set the correct encording (Nr3) to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks BastianW, that was the problem but I didnt understood it at first on how to fix during the importation of the file.

Comment: Hm, but this was mentioned as solution 1 in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the support.
I've done some tests and found out that during importation the names were coming wrong, so, I've saved the input file as .csv UNICODE UTF-8. Did the tests again and everything is fine now.
Didn't know about that, but it is fixed now.

Thanks!

more info: http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/thernandez/archive/2015/09/20/how-to-export-and-import-foreign-characters-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

I used this to change several Shared mailboxes at once.

Create a 'c:\users.csv' that looks like this with the email addresses of your Shared Mailboxes you want to change in the left column under 'ident' and the new display name you want in the right column under 'displayname'.

```
ident,displayname
user1@domain.com,New Display Name1
user2@domain.com,New Display Name2
user3@domain.com,New Display Name3
```

Then, you can copy and paste this into PowerShell if you have the Exchange Module installed and you are logged into a session.

```
Import-Csv C:\users.csv|ForEach{Set-Mailbox -Identity $_.ident -DisplayName $_.displayname}
```